# Defining a dictionary using a zipped list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

```
drinks = ["espresso", "chai", "decaf", "drip"]
caffeine = [64, 40, 0, 120]
zipped_drinks = zip(drinks, caffeine)

#Uncomment below
#print('list here:', list(zipped_drinks))

drinks_to_caffeine = {key:value for key, value in zipped_drinks}

print('dictionary here:', drinks_to_caffeine)
```

So my problem is when I uncomment print statement with the list statement. This happens even without the print. After using the list statement, the dictionary `drinks_to_caffeine` will return empty, but it will display the list. The dictionary will then work again if I don't have the list statement.

Is this a normal behavior?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35395860/looping-zipped-list-in-python.   That's the same problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`zip` is "lazy": it returns an iterator, which consumes the iterators it was originally given:

```py
>>> drinks = ["espresso", "chai", "decaf", "drip"]
>>> caffeine = [64, 40, 0, 120]
>>> zip(drinks, caffeine)
<zip object at 0x7fea721f5f40>
```

That means you can only iterate over the return value of `zip` once, and the `list` constructor already did that iteration:

```py
>>> zipped_drinks = zip(drinks, caffeine)
>>> list(zipped_drinks)
[('espresso', 64), ('chai', 40), ('decaf', 0), ('drip', 120)]
>>> list(zipped_drinks)
[]
```

A solution is to convert the `zip` result to a list right away:

```py
zipped_drinks = list(zip(drinks, caffeine))
print('list here:', zipped_drinks)
drinks_to_caffeine = dict(zipped_drinks)
print('dictionary here:', drinks_to_caffeine)
```

Notice the use of the `dict` constructor, which is just a shorter way to achieve the same result as your dict comprehension.

Answer (score 2):

Coming from documentation for [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip)

> Make an iterator that aggregates elements from each of the iterables.
> Returns an **iterator** of tuples, where the i-th tuple contains the i-th
> element from each of the argument sequences or iterables.

Yes that is completely normal because **zip** returns an **iterator** and iterators are evaluated only once, so when you uncomment your print statement, the iterator is evaluated at that time, and later when you try to form dictionary out of the zip object, the iterator has nothing at all, all the values are already **yielded** by that time.

The code snippet from [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```py
def zip(*iterables):
    # zip('ABCD', 'xy') --> Ax By
    sentinel = object()
    iterators = [iter(it) for it in iterables]
    while iterators:
        result = []
        for it in iterators:
            elem = next(it, sentinel)
            if elem is sentinel:
                return
            result.append(elem)
        yield tuple(result)
```